# How to show a left or right decomposed tree structure using json data in javascript/AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, tree, treeview

I have a set of data which are inter-connected and has to be shown in tree format on left or right expansion depending on the type of data.

Below is the link which i have replicated but we need customization on levels and what comes under what has to be controlled using a configuration page or something.

[Orientation Controlled Example](http://fperucic.github.io/treant-js/examples/connectors/)

I wanted to check if we have any library which gives us more good UI in terms of leveling and also the customization as well?

Below is one of the thing which is the expected result but there is no customization and also no orienation from left or right

[Tennis example](http://fperucic.github.io/treant-js/examples/tennis-draw/)